# Populate an array one value at a time

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement

I want to run through each cell in a column and if a condition is met place it into the next available array element.

I have the first part but I don't know how to place each element that meets the IF statement criteria into an array and then transpose that array.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim StepCheck As Range
Dim ImporterName As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NameRange As Range

Set ws = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Filepath goes here").Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each StepCheck In ws.Range("F1:F" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)

    If IsError(StepCheck.Value) Then
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        
    ElseIf StepCheck.Value = "5" Then

        ImporterName = StepCheck.Offset(0, -5).Value
    
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

How do I store every StepCheck when it meets the IF statement criteria into the array importer name?

The code runs but doesn't store all of the StepCheck entries into the array and instead gets overwritten every loop.

Comment: `ImporterName` is not an array, it's just a variant. You need to declare an array and set its size and then you can index its elements.

Comment: I don't know the size of the array, I only know its as big as the ws.Range in the For loop, id have to make it dynamic somehow

Comment: You can either make it larger than you'll possibly need at the start or use `resize` method to be dynamic. Plenty of info around on this.

Comment: Yeah okay, ```ReDim``` by range count and using the ```ImporterName(StepCheck.Row)``` seems to work fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Match Data

- It will return the values from column `A` from the rows where the value in column `F` is equal to `5` in a 1D array and print its contents in the Immediate window.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MatchData()

    ' (Open and) Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Test.xlsx")
    ' For the workbook containing this code, use:
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Write the values from the source lookup column
    ' to a 2D one-based one-column array ('slData').
    
    Dim slrg As Range
    Set slrg = sws.Range("F1", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slrg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim slData() As Variant
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim slData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): slData(1, 1) = slrg.Value
    Else
        slData = slrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write the values from the source value column
    ' to a 2D one-based one-column array ('svData').
    
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns("A")
    
    Dim svData() As Variant
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim svData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): svData(1, 1) = svrg.Value
    Else
        svData = svrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write the required values from the source values array
    ' to a 1D one-based array ('dArr').
    
    Dim dArr() As Variant: ReDim dArr(1 To srCount) ' too big
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sValue = slData(sr, 1)
        If VarType(sValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            If sValue = 5 Then ' is equal to 5
                dc = dc + 1
                dArr(dc) = svData(sr, 1)
            ' Else ' is a number but not equal to 5; do nothing
            End If
        ' Else ' is not a number; do nothing
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Resize the destination array (remove the trailing 'empties').
    ReDim Preserve dArr(1 To dc)

    ' Print the contents of the array to the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G').
    Debug.Print "Index", "Value"
    For dc = 1 To UBound(dArr)
        Debug.Print dc, dArr(dc)
    Next dc
 
End Sub
```